# Posting to Facebook wall using HttpMethod.POST unity3D

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

well I am using unity and trying to post on my wall... I imported the Facebook sdk and i used the code in their docs which is

```
int score = 10000;

var scoreData = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"score", score.ToString()}};

FB.API ("/me/scores", HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, scoreData);
```

and i have allowed the publish settings (when i logged in ) still nothing happens .. 
so here is my code exactly

```
    void Awake(){
    FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);



}

private void SetInit(){
    Debug.Log("IN");



}

private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown){

    if (!isGameShown) {
        Time.timeScale=0;

    }


    else {

        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

}
    void FBlogin()
{if (!FB.IsLoggedIn) {

                    FB.Login ("email,publish_actions", AuthCallback);
            }
    else {  if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            //  Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight;


            Dictionary<string,string> score1=new Dictionary<string, string>();
            score1.Add("Score","100");



            FB.API ("/me/scores",Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, AuthCallback, score1);
            Debug.Log("Okay");




        } 


            }
}


void AuthCallback(FBResult result){
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
    //  Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight;

        int score = 10000;

        Dictionary<string,string> scoreData = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"score", score.ToString()}};

        FB.API ("me/scores", HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, scoreData);


        Dictionary<string,string> scoreData1 = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"score", "0"}};





    } 


    else {
        Debug.Log("FB LOGIN ERROR");        


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I found what was I doing wrong if you want to post to Facebook

```
    FB.API ("/me/feed", HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback,   new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"access_token", FB.AccessToken},{"message","Test"}});
```

and instead of "test" write your post .. this happens automatically without the fb dialog (you need to enable post on my behalf of course..)